# Slow Performance in the application with roles customizing. DevExpress eXpressAppFramework(XAF)

Tags: performance, frameworks, devexpress, xaf

I have an application with middler tier architecture., .net framework 4.0 and devexpress version 13.2.8.

I am creating a new role and asigning it to a user, when this user logs in, 
it takes about 20 to 60 seconds to login. Howeve, if other user with administrator role logs in it takes 1 second. this behavior 
is also frequent in other functionalities like Listview, look up objects, etc.

Can you please indicate us some information to review about this topic.

Comment: The best place to ask is the [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center) where you can post a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons for this, but I could guess it is probably because admin doesn't need to check IsGranted to permission requests. I recommend you to check how this method affects your performance.

For instance, you can find that permission requests checks to AuditDataItemPersistent can be heavy and unecessary, so you can override SecurityStrategyComplex class and skip it:

```
public override bool IsGranted(IPermissionRequest permissionRequest)
    {
        //Always grant for AuditDataItemPresistent for performance reasons.
        if (permissionRequest is ClientPermissionRequest)
            if (typeof(AuditDataItemPersistent).IsAssignableFrom(((ClientPermissionRequest)(permissionRequest)).ObjectType))
                return true;

        return base.IsGranted(permissionRequest);
    }
```